# How can I prevent overloading for extern "C" functions?

Tags: c++, compilation, extern, overloading

I'm writing a c++ library that exposes some functions which are used only by C# code. However, as I accidently mistyped the paramter, I found that this code can be succesfully compiled and linked even without any warning as long as I don't use the (not mistyped version) function in the cpp file.

```
struct Dummy { int a; double b; };
extern "C" void SetArray(Dummy* x, int cnt);
void SetArray(Dummy x, int cnt)
{
    // a TODO placeholder.
}
```

How can I let compiler throw an error or a warning for this case? The compiler option -Wall is set but there's still no warning. Using tdmgcc 5.1.0.

Comment: @doctorlove Look at the first parameter of SetArray, and this looks causing an overload...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make some assertion that will fail if function is overloaded:

```
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<void (Dummy *, int), decltype(SetArray)>);
```

> error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Comment: It works! Thanks. Although I'm using C++11 and have to find another way similar to that...

Comment: @Apliex-Ddr To work with c++11 this snippet requires only a few changes: use of `::std::is_same` and mandatory assertion message.

Comment: Wait, where do you put that assertion? IINM the compiler should already prevent you from overloading the function once it has seen the `extern "C"` declaration...

Comment: @Quentin: Are you absolutely sure about that? I can imagine wanting to expose one overload to C, but keep the convenience of other overloads in C++. Now, I would use namespaces and separate C and C++ headers, effectively nullifying this situation, but I don't see why you could not provide a non-`extern "C"` overload of an `extern "C"` function.

Comment: @rubenvb I just tested it on Coliru and indeed you can overload `extern "C"` functions just fine. I'm confused.

Comment: @Quentin You weren't entirely imagining things. See my answer.

Comment: This can be applied for all cases, not just extern C. (right?)

Comment: I'd make it signature-agnostic. `!std::is_void_v<decltype(SetArray)>` is just as good, and has less characters to type.

Answer (score 13):

You can include `extern "C"` in the definition as well as the declaration.

```
struct Dummy { int a; double b; };
extern "C" void SetArray(Dummy* x, int cnt);
extern "C" void SetArray(Dummy x, int cnt)
{
    // a TODO placeholder.
}
```

Quentin's comment on VTT's answer was halfway there: it's not that C functions cannot be overloaded, it's that C functions cannot be overloaded with other C functions. The compiler will enforce this, but it can only do so if you explicitly specify you want a C function in both declarations.

Comment: Possible justification for this behaviour: to the linker, both C structs in your example will have the same name (hence you have conflicting definitions), whereas the C++ struct in the OP's example will have a mangled name which is different from the C structure name.

Comment: @grahamj42: I saw this in a header file: `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" long strtol(const char *input, const char **endptr, int base); extern "C" long strtol(char *input, char **endptr, int base); #else long strtol(const char *input, char **endptr, int base); #endif`

Comment: @Joshua That's problematic for other reasons too (using non-reserved names). Where did you see that?

Comment: @hvd: In the compiler's `string.h`

Comment: @Joshua That part was obvious. Which compiler?

Comment: @hvd: Borland C++ 4.5

Comment: @Joshua That's so old it predates the C++ standard though.